# How to get index number of specific tag and class by searching some text?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have following html

```
<ul class="vote_list clearfix" id="vote_div">                    
    <li class="vote_one">
        <div class="vote_show">
            <div class="vote_T1">Chelsea</div>
            <div class="vote_state">
                <div class="vote_ST1">Votes：30000</div>
                <div class="vote_ST2">Ranking：1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="vote_date">
            <div class="vote_T1">Chelsea</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="vote_one">
        <div class="vote_show">
            <div class="vote_T1">Arsenal</div>
            <div class="vote_state">
                <div class="vote_ST1">Votes：20000</div>
                <div class="vote_ST2">Ranking：2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="vote_date">
            <div class="vote_T1">Arsenal</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="vote_one">
        <div class="vote_show">
            <div class="vote_T1">Liverpool</div>
            <div class="vote_state">
                <div class="vote_ST1">Votes：10000</div>
                <div class="vote_ST2">Ranking：3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="vote_date">
            <div class="vote_T1">Liverpool</div>
        </div>
    </li>
<ul>
```

I want to extract total vote of Chelsea, so it should show Votes: 30000

My idea is Which `<li class="vote_one">` own `Chelsea` text and it should return `0` since `Chelsea` located on first `vote_one` element

But I don't know how to convert my idea to code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you try your idea?

Comment: @Dark Cyber your question title asks for index, your question description asks for showing votes and your own answer shows votes and rank as well. So I included an answer with simpler and clearer code and details on how to get all of these things in a simple way. I hope it helps :) If you find it useful, mark my answer as accepted answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved @Idlehands

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(full_content, "lxml")

i=0
for vote_one_list in soup.find_all("li", class_="vote_one"):
        if vote_one_list.find("div", class_="vote_show").find("div", class_="vote_T1").text == "Chelsea":
                total_vote = soup.find_all("li", class_="vote_one")[i].find("div", class_="vote_show").find("div", class_="vote_state").find("div", class_="vote_ST1").text
                rank = soup.find_all("li", class_="vote_one")[i].find("div", class_="vote_show").find("div", class_="vote_state").find("div", class_="vote_ST2").text
                print "Chelsea | "+ rank + " | "+total_vote
        i = i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Printing the `votes` and `rank`

The simplest way to get the votes for any given input would be:

```
input_str = 'Chelsea'

for vote in soup.find_all('div', class_='vote_show'):
    if vote.find('div', class_='vote_T1').get_text().strip() == input_str:
        print(vote.find('div', class_='vote_ST1').get_text().strip()) # Prints votes
        print(vote.find('div', class_='vote_ST2').get_text().strip()) # Prints rank
```

The solution looks at all `<div class='vote_show'>` to check if text in the  `<div class='vote_T1'>` is same as input string, `Chelsea`, for example.

I added the `strip()` so that you can find a match even if there are spaces around the string. If a match is found, the text of the contained `<div class='vote_ST1'>` is printed, again stripping any surrounding whitespace.

## Printing the index

You can modify the `for` loop to use `enumerate()` as follows:

```
for idx, vote in enumerate(soup.find_all('div', class_='vote_show')):
    if vote.find('div', class_='vote_T1').get_text().strip() == input_str:
        print(idx) # prints index
        print(vote.find('div', class_='vote_ST1').get_text().strip()) # prints votes
        print(vote.find('div', class_='vote_ST2').get_text().strip()) # prints rank
```

Enumerate allows us to loop over something and have an automatic counter.

If you want to stop looking any further once you've found a match, you can add a `break` statement after the `print()` statement.